# D-LINK DSR-250N lan issues

Tags: local-area-network, timeout, host, wlan

I'm having problem with my DSR-250N router.

I set-up local network with 10 computers. Some of them are connected through wire and some use wireless.

The problem is, sometimes one computer cannot ping another - no matter if is using wire / wireless.

It lasts for some time, then i'm able to ping this machine, and again after some time I'm getting Time Out / Host is down.

I disabled windows firewall, but without help.

Much appreciate your help!

Comment: Why do you need to ping these machines?

Comment: @joeqwerty Let me be more specific - I wasn't clear from the beginning. I'm running some software on one machine (A) in LAN network. I'd like the other machines within the same LAN (cable / wireless) to be able to connect to the software I'm running on (A). However sometimes it is not possible because computers in my LAN cannot talk to each other.

Answer (score 1):

D-link is a world leader of *crapware*, so you probably should switch D-link to someting decent and see if it helps.

*Note: This advice is more helping that it seems at first look. I saved more networks with simply changing [D|TP]-link switches to Catalyst ones more times than I have answers accepted here.*